# How to compute the determinant of this Hermitian Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-calculus

Given numbers $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $\beta, \omega \in \mathbb{C}$, we construct the matrix $H_n(\omega)$ that is defined as follows:

\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta & \beta^2 & \ddots & \beta^{n-1} & \omega \\
\overline{\beta} & \alpha & \beta & \ddots & \ddots & \beta^{n-1} \\
\overline{\beta}^2 & \overline{\beta} & \alpha & \ddots & \beta^{2} & \ddots \\
\ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \beta^2 \\
\overline{\beta}^{n-1} & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \beta \\
\overline{\omega} & \overline{\beta}^{n-1} & \ddots & \overline{\beta}^{2} & \overline{\beta} & \alpha \\ \end{pmatrix}

For which values of the parameter $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$ is the following hermitian matrix nonsingular? I also would like to determine whether the determinant is positive or negative and find the number of negative eigenvalues.

Comment: You may find this useful: http://icms.kaist.ac.kr/mathnet/kms_tex/100251.pdf